# Date format and date format conversion and output issues

Tags: python, datetime

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4j1g4.png)
Why are these projects not showing results when I run them so far?
Thanks guys

I have tried to run them but no results are displayed after Print and some of these in spyder also do not show results in console.I want them to be run

Comment: Show code and other textual information as properly formatted text in the question, not as comment, image or external link.

Comment: If you run that code you **will** get a result. The result will be a NameError exception

Answer (score 1):

You define your first variable as `birth_date`, and then reference it later as `birth_date_str`. Change these two to be the same and it will work correctly.

What version of python are you using? Later versions, such as 3.11, will give an error message similar to `Did you mean: 'birth_date'?`, which can help with debugging.

Please in the future post code with proper formatting, not an image file :)